# JQuery dynamic list prevent multiple clicks on same item

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, mobile

Is there a way to disable a button after it's been clicked once, so the user doesn't accidentally click an item multiple times?

I have a jQuery list, populated from a JSON array. Here's a sample of the code. I need to add functionality in here to disable the click callback after it's been clicked once.

If my question is unclear, please tell me so I can edit it with what's missing.

Thanks !!

```
$('div[data-url*="details.page?productId"]').live("pageshow", function() {

var productId = getParameterByName("productId", $(this).data("url"));

$.mobile.pageLoading();

var product = catalog.products[productId];
$(this).find('#productName').text(product.name);
$(this).find('#productBrand').html(product.brand);
$(this).find('#productPrice').html(product.price);
$(this).find('#productDescription').html(product.description);
$(this).find('#productThumbnail').attr("src", product.thumbnail);
$(this).find('#add-to-cart').attr("product-item-id", productId);
$(this).find('#productSalePrice').html(product.salePrice);
$(this).find('#productSaleDesc').html(product.sale_desc);
$(this).find('#productCategory').html(product.category);
$(this).find('#longDescription').html(product.longDesc);

for (k = 1; k <= parseInt(product.rating); k++) {
    var starId = "#star" + k;
    $(this).find(starId).attr('src', '/pub/3/resources/ti/store/mobile/star-fill_30x25.png')
}

if (product.salePrice == '') {
    $(this).find('#productPrice').css('text-decoration', 'none')

}

else if (product.price > product.salePrice) {
    $(this).find('#productPrice').css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
    $(this).find('#salePrice').html(product.salePrice);
    $(this).find('#saleDesc').html(product.sale_desc);

}

$.mobile.pageLoading(true);


});


function refreshList() {
console.debug('About to refresh with sort type : ' + sortType);

switch (sortType) {
    case 'sort-a-z':
        catalog.products.sort(sort_by('name', false));
        break;
    case 'sort-z-a':
        catalog.products.sort(sort_by('name', true));
        break;
    case 'sort-price-up':
        catalog.products.sort(sort_by('price', false, parseFloat));
        break;
    case 'sort-price-down':
        catalog.products.sort(sort_by('price', true, parseFloat));
        break;
    default :

}

var items = [];


$.each(catalog.products,
      function(index, value) {

          if (
                  ((!filterValue ) || value.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue.toUpperCase()) != -1)
                          && ((!brand) || value.brand.toUpperCase().indexOf(brand.toUpperCase()) != -1)
                          && ((!category) || value.category.toUpperCase().indexOf(category.toUpperCase()) != -1)
                          && ((!sport) || value.sport.toUpperCase().indexOf(sport.toUpperCase()) != -1)
                  ) {

              var priceInfo;
              if(value.salePrice === '') {
                  priceInfo = '<h4 style="margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:0px;color:#75a8db "> $' + value.price + '</h4></a></li>';
              } else {
                  priceInfo = '<h4 style="margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:0px; "><span style="text-decoration: line-through;font-size:small;">$' + value.price +
                          '</span><span style="color:#75a8db;"> $' + value.salePrice + '</span></h4></a></li>';
              }

              items.push('<li id="' + index + '">' +
                      '<a data-identity="productId"  href="./details.page?productId=' + index + '" >' +
                      '<img class="ui-li-thumb" src="' + value.thumbnail + '"/>' +
                      '<p style="margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:0px;">' + value.brand + '</p>' +
                      '<h3 style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">' + value.name + '</h3>' +
                      priceInfo);



      }}
        );

if (items.length === 0) {
    items.push('<p style="text-align: left;margin-left: 10px">No results found.</p>');
}
productListView.html(items.join(''));
productListView.listview('refresh');


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably binding click handlers using [`.click(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/click), right?
If so, just use [`.one('click', ...)`](http://api.jquery.com/one) instead.

Comment: Wow, never knew about the "one" function in jquery. Do you know which version it was added in?

Comment: The API docs show the "version added" for every method. `.one()` was added in jQuery 1.1.

Comment: @JFFF thanks for editing the question to include more code, but I don't see where any sort of click callback is bound. Could you clarify, or possibly provide some sort of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Actually let me rephrase my question. 

I just need a way to disable the link so it cant be clicked more then once.

Basically, the list is populated. The user clicks an item (link), this link is then disabled so it cannot be clicked multiple times, the user is redirected to the "details" page of the item, he comes back, the link is clickable again.

Answer (score 0):

This should be all you need

```
$(li).click(function(){
  $(this).unbind('click'); 
  //do whatever you want here
});
```

**EDIT:** If you want to remove a link on click just do this

```
$('.item a').one('click',function(){
  $(this).attr('href','javascript:void(0)');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This should work but I'm not sure how to implement it in my code. I updated my first post with the full code. If you can point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: There's no event listeners in that code, are you looking to disable the link after it's been clicked once?

Comment: If the user leaves the page on link click then there's no way for the page's JavaScript to know that that link has been clicked once they get back there unless you put data into the cookie. Why does it matter if they click more than once anyways?

Comment: When tested on iPhone, it's easy to click multiple times even if it's not on purpose. When that happens, if the user tries to go back the ajax gets messed up and multiple clicks on the back button are needed to get back to this original page.

Comment: I just need to find a way to disable the click to avoid multiple clicks on an item. I don't need it to be disabled forever. 

What I want to do is : 
User clicks link. 
Link is disabled and user is taken to next page.
User comes back to previous page ; Link is active again.

Comment: It still doesnt work but it must be something else in my code. I'll try and figure it out, cheers !

Answer (score 0):

You can bind using "one" method instead of bind (and reattach it again and again when needed).

But more flexible pattern is to bind on something (say, classname), remove that classname and reattach it when needed - this works with life events.

```
$("div.clickme").live("click", function() {
   $(this).removeClass("clickme")
   ...
   $(this).addClass("clickme")
})
```

You can also combine this technique with using setTimeout or something.